# Holiday Calendar in pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dataframe, calendar

I created a Holiday calendar for Germany (not all days included) as followed:

```
from pandas.tseries.holiday import Holiday,AbstractHolidayCalendar

class GermanHolidays(AbstractHolidayCalendar):
    rules = [Holiday('New Years Day', month=1, day=1),
             Holiday('First of May', month=5, day=1),
             Holiday('German Unity Day', month=10,day=3),
            ...]

cal = GermanHolidays()
```

Now I want that a column displays when a holiday appears or not with ("1" or "0"). So I did the following:

```
holidays = cal.holidays(start=X['Time (CET)'].min(), end = X['Time (CET)'].max())
X['Holidays'] = X['Time (CET)'].isin(holidays)
X['Holidays'] = X['Holidays'].astype(float)
```

X is a dataframe where `Time (CET)` is column in the format `%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S`. Unfortunately this is not working. There is no error raised but all columns are marked with `"0"`. So there is no matching happening and I really dont know why. 
I thought that it is maybe because the frequency of holidays is daily and not hourly as it is in the column `Time (CET)`.
Would be great if you could help me! Thank you!

Comment: This might be happening because `X['Time (CET)']` contains date-strings instead of `datetime64`s. What is the value of `X['Time (CET)'].dtype`?

Comment: Thanks for the remark. The column is in dtype datetime64s. Sorry for not mentioning!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There might be a few reasons for that.

One of them [as mentioned by @unutbu - is a wrong (string) dtype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45654473/holiday-calendar-in-pandas-dataframe#comment78267241_45654473). Make sure your `X['Time (CET)']` column is of `datetime` dtype. This can be done as follows:

```
X['Time (CET)'] = pd.to_datetime(X['Time (CET)'], dayfirst=True, errors='coerce')
```

Another reason as you said is the time part.

Here is a demo:

```
In [28]: df = pd.DataFrame({'Date':pd.date_range('2017-01-01 01:01:01', 
                                                 freq='9H', periods=1000)})
```

yields:

```
In [30]: df
Out[30]:
                   Date
0   2017-01-01 01:01:01
1   2017-01-01 10:01:01
2   2017-01-01 19:01:01
3   2017-01-02 04:01:01
4   2017-01-02 13:01:01
5   2017-01-02 22:01:01
6   2017-01-03 07:01:01
7   2017-01-03 16:01:01
8   2017-01-04 01:01:01
9   2017-01-04 10:01:01
..                  ...
990 2018-01-07 07:01:01
991 2018-01-07 16:01:01
992 2018-01-08 01:01:01
993 2018-01-08 10:01:01
994 2018-01-08 19:01:01
995 2018-01-09 04:01:01
996 2018-01-09 13:01:01
997 2018-01-09 22:01:01
998 2018-01-10 07:01:01
999 2018-01-10 16:01:01

[1000 rows x 1 columns]
```

filtering by `holidays` isn't working because of not matching time part:

```
In [29]: df.loc[df.Date.isin(holidays)]
Out[29]:
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Date]
Index: []
```

We can make it working by normalizing (truncate time part or set time to `00:00:00`) our datetime column:

```
In [31]: df.loc[df.Date.dt.normalize().isin(holidays)]
Out[31]:
                   Date
0   2017-01-01 01:01:01
1   2017-01-01 10:01:01
2   2017-01-01 19:01:01
320 2017-05-01 01:01:01
321 2017-05-01 10:01:01
322 2017-05-01 19:01:01
734 2017-10-03 07:01:01
735 2017-10-03 16:01:01
```

Comment: Hey thanks a lot this worked. Somehow I got the problem that on the first of January I do not get returned a holiday. I think its due to the fact that the day starts in my data with 01:00 a.m. How could I work around this?

Comment: @inneb, could you provide a small reproducible data set, so i could reproduce it?

Answer (score 1):

This is basically what you already have.  Given that this works and yours doesn't, it is likely because the values are text instead of timestamps as noted already by @unutbu and @MaxU.

Also, your post states:

> displays when a holiday appears or not with ("1" or "0")

Did you really want a text value?  You tried to convert to floats, but you probably just want integers.

```
X = pd.DataFrame({'Time (CET)': pd.DatetimeIndex(start='2017-01-01', end='2017-12-31', freq='12H')})
X = X.assign(Holidays=X['Time (CET)'].isin(cal.holidays()).astype(int))
>>> X
             Time (CET)  Holidays
0   2017-01-01 00:00:00         1
1   2017-01-01 12:00:00         0
2   2017-01-02 00:00:00         0
...
```